# PL/SQL fill variable with if-condition value

Tags: sql, variables, plsql

i am trying to fill a variable in PL/SQL with an if-condition value
like this:

`v_variable := if(4 > 3) THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END;`

but this doesnt work.

Are there any options to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this with an `if`, I'd go with `case`:

```
 v_variable := case when 4>3 then 'A' else 'B' end;
```

Comment: This was the right hint for me. 
Except: Instead of := I had to use = (in Oracle SQL Developer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF (4 > 3) THEN 
  v_variable :='A'; 
ELSE
  v_variable :='B'; 
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign **`If condition`** value in **`PL/SQL`**. your assignment is work in **`Python`** language but not in PL/SQL so you can avoid to this way and use **`IF condition`** in **`main logic block (BEGIN block)`**.

```
DECLARE
   v_variable VARCHAR2 := 'B';
BEGIN

   IF 4 > 3 THEN
      v_variable := 'A';
   END IF;

   -- display the values of v_variable
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('v_variable value = '|| v_variable);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS278):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_variable VARCHAR2(1);
  3  BEGIN
  4     v_variable := CASE WHEN 4 > 3 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END;
  5     dbms_output.put_line(v_variable);
  6  END;
  7  /
A
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```